# Permission denied on S3 path - What are the minimum policies required on the data source to get athena-express to work?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm attempting to use the Athena-express node module to query Athena.

Per the Athena-express docs:

> This IAM role/user must have AmazonAthenaFullAccess and AmazonS3FullAccess policies attached
> Note: As an alternative to granting AmazonS3FullAccess you could granularize and limit write access to a specific bucket. Just specify this bucket name during athena-express initialization"

> Providing AmazonS3FullAccess to this micro service is a non-starter. What is the minimum set of priviledges I can grant to the micro service and still get around the "Permission denied on S3 path: s3://..." errors I've been getting?

Currently, I've got the following

***Output location:*** (I don't think the problem is here)

`s3:AbortMultipartUpload, s3:CreateMultipartUpload, s3:DeleteObject, s3:Get*, s3:List*, s3:PutObject, s3:PutObjectTagging`
on `"arn:aws:s3:::[my-bucket-name]/tmp/athena" and "arn:aws:s3:::[my-bucket-name]/tmp/athena/*"`

***Data source location:***

`s3:GetBucketLocation`
on `"arn:aws:s3:::*"`

`s3:ListBucket`
on `"arn:aws:s3:::[my-bucket-name]"`

`s3:Get* and s3:List*`
on `"arn:aws:s3:::[my-bucket-name]/production/[path]/[path]" and "arn:aws:s3:::[my-bucket-name]/production/[path]/[path]/*`"

The error message I get with the above is:
"**Permission denied on S3 path: s3://[my-bucket-name]/production/[path]/[path]/v1/dt=2022-05-26/.hoodie_partition_metadata**"

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the bucket storing the data I needed to query was encrypted, which meant that the missing permission to query was kms:Decrypt.

Athena by outputs the results of a query to a location (which athena-express then retrieves). The location of the output was in that same encrypted bucket, so I also ended up giving my cronjob kms:Encrypt and kms:GeneratedDataKey.

I ended up using CloudTrails to figure out which permissions were causing my queries to fail.